# Set the data in render method after pre-declaration in Django

Tags: python, django, cookies, django-middleware

I have declared the variable as given below:

```
response = render( request, 'authme/login.html', {} )
```

At some point of time, I need to set the temporary cookie and pass the value of temporary cookie in the view.

I tried the following ways to set the data as given below:

1. response['message'] = "Login Failed: Please try again"
2. response.message = "Login Failed: Please try again"

Can anyone suggest how can I set the message part using variable "response", in the same way, How do we use for setting cookie, PFB:

```
response.set_cookie('message','Login Failed: Please try again')
```

So that it is equivalent to this line of statement:

```
response = render( request, 'authme/login.html', {"message":"Login Failed: Please try again"})
```

Comment: I don't think this would be possible, since calling `render()` merges your `context` with the `template` provided. This can be seen by printing the data via `print(response.content)`. You would have to just create another response with new render params.

Comment: Thank you @Hybrid, That's helpful in not chasing what I was up for from some couple of hours. You saved my further time.

Answer (score 3):

Please refer to [Django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/), you can pass messages from views:

```
messages.error(request, 'Login Failed')
messages.success(request, 'Successfully Logged in.'
```

And you can use these messages using Jinja2 in your HTML:

```
{% if messages %}
<ul class="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you +nimish, This is what I was looking for, That's a pretty standard way to achieve what I was looking for.